# missing library libX11.so.6 for openjdk:12-jdk docker container

Tags: java, selenium, docker, webdriver, yum

I have a Dockerfile that is from `openjdk-12-jdk`. In my application a dependency (https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) apperently requires the libX11.so.6 library, as the application fails to start with

`/usr/src/app/etc/chromedriver/linux64/75.0.3770.8/chromdriver: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I tried `yum whatprovides libX11.so.6`, which returned

```
bash-4.2# yum whatprovides libX11.so.6
Loaded plugins: ovl
libX11-1.6.5-1.el7.i686 : Core X11 protocol client library
Repo        : ol7_latest
Matched from:
Provides    : libX11.so.6



libX11-1.6.5-2.el7.i686 : Core X11 protocol client library
Repo        : ol7_latest
Matched from:
Provides    : libX11.so.6



libX11-1.6.5-1.el7.i686 : Core X11 protocol client library
Repo        : @ol7_latest
Matched from:
Provides    : libX11.so.6
```

So I added `RUN yum -y install libX11-1.6.5-1.el7.i686` to my Dockerfile.

But the error remains and it still fails with the same error as written above.

So I tried `yum install libX11.i686` directly inside of the container, but again with no success for the application

How can I get this library ? Or is this not possible with the `oraclelinux`, that is the basis of the `openjdk-12-jdk` docker ?

===== EDIT ====

as I try to start chromedriver for a selenium test, I also tried to call it headless, but also the same error occurrs

Comment: I solved my problem, although not sure if this would be a valid answer.

I switched from the `openjdk-12-jdk` to centos and installed openjdk manually.
I installed google chrome and start my tests in headless mode.

This is my workaround, but not the actual answer to the problem

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command to add missing component:

```
yum -y install libX11
```